# Airflow run jupyter

Tags: airflow

please help everyone

Currently I am setting up anaconda and airflow on 2 docker containers.
I have mapped the jupyter code file to airflow's dags folder.
But currently airflow only receives the .py file but not the .ipynb file.
Although in the .ipynb file I used PapermillOperator.
How can airflow call dags from .ipynb file

How can airflow call dags from .ipynb file ?